# Why is my promise not resolving when using async/await with nightmarejs?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, nightmare

Using the latest nightmarejs release. When I run this code it just freezes.  The goal is just to grab an a element and see if it has an href.

```
var hasHref = async function(nightmare) {
    var selector = '.pagination > ul > li.active + li > a'
    try {
        var hasHref = await nightmare.evaluate((selector) => {
            return document.querySelector(selector).hasAttribute('href')
        }, selector)

        return hasHref;
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        nightmare.end()
    }
}

const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
nightmare.goto(mysite)
hrefBool = hasHref(nightmare)
console.log(hrefBool)
nightmare.wait(5000).end()
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere, where `hasHref` is being called. Can you please provide a full [mcve] so we can attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry I had changed the code to simplify it. It was named nextPage and I changed it to hasHref for simplification. It's fixed now.

Comment: `hrefBool` is not a boolean, it's a promise!

Comment: You probably will want to call `hasRef` only after `.goto()` has completed

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume you have defined `nightmare` and `mysite` appropriately. Then the only concern is if the selector doesn't find a match, you'll be trying to get `hasAttribute` of null. Instead you could write:

```
const element = document.querySelector(selector);
return element ? element.hasAttribute('href') : false;
```

Otherwise the code works for me, so if you're still having problems, you might need to give some more details about your setup if possible.